# Set up SSL in Elastic Beanstalk using cloudHSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hsm

I'm familiar with creating a CSR (via openssl) on a webserver and submitting it to a CA to purchase an SSL cert.

A site we're building (using Elastic Beanstalk) has a requirement that certificates are managed via a HSM. I *think* AWS CloudHSM is the correct tool to use here? I have:

- Created the EB environment in a VPC with public and private subnets
- Requested and assigned an SSL cert to the environment via AWS Cert
  Manager *(at this point, I have a working site over https, just no HSM)*
- Created a HSM cluster in the same VPC, and downloaded its
  CSR.

At this point, the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/initialize-cluster.html#sign-csr) leave me a bit stuck.

It says, "Your CA signs the CSR, which creates a signed certificate. Then you provide the signed certificate and your CA's issuing certificate to initialize the cluster."

Fine. Except if I try to upload this CSR to (ie, Verisign, GlobalSign) I get "Certificates with internal names are no longer permitted". Which makes sense - I'm not requesting a cert for a site's external domain name, the cert is for the HSM: which, I'm guessing, I'll then use to create an openssl cert once its CSR has been signed.

Basically, I'm very confused about how a HSM fits into the otherwise simple SSL-requesting procedure of: generate CSR, submit to CA, install cert on webserver. Especially given my added complications of doing this all with Elastic Beanstalk and AWS ACM rather than just dumping a cert file on the server and updating the Nginx conf.

How does it all *work* ??

Comment: "A requirement that certificates are managed by an HSM."  Are you saying that the SSL certificates for your web servers have to be managed by an HSM? (?!!?) Using CloudHSM costs in excess of $1,000/month.  That does not seem sensible... nor is it easy to imagine what the benefit might be.  What's the underlying requirement?

Comment: Also note from the docs: *"To sign the cluster's CSR, you typically use a* **private** *certificate authority (CA)."*  (Not a public one).  If your organization doesn't have a private CA, it adds to the difficulty of understanding the HSM requirement.

Comment: The client is a bank. The requirement is that the SSL certificate "is stored on a FIPS compliant Hardware Security Module (HSM)".

Regarding the public/private CA; this perhaps touches on my (probably totally inaccurate) understanding of where this HSM will fit in, which runs roughly thus: browsers need a chain to a public CA in order to trust the SSL cert. We would get the HSM's CSR signed by a public CA, which would then allow us to use it to generate/store a SSL cert for the site.

Comment: To me, it looks like the HSM needs a certificate only to provide assurance that *you* (your systems that access it) can trust that the HSM itself isn't being impersonated when you interact with it.   This cert really has nothing to do with your web site certs. By creating your own private CA, which can be done with openssl, you can sign the HSM's cert yourself, and then use your private CA's certificate when interacting with the HSM, to ensure that the cert it presents back to you is valid.

Comment: If requirement is that the SSL *certificate* be stored securely, then that requirement is somewhat laughable, because SSL certificates are public by design -- every time you connect to an SSL-capable web server, it gives you a copy of its certificate.  The SSL certificate's *private key* may be what's being referred to, here, in which case, your external-facing SSL cert's private key is already stored encrypted, by ACM, using keys managed by KMS.  You could store your own certs' private keys, encrypted, and use KMS to manage that encryption, as well.  The requirement seems reality-deficient.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear; obviously it's the private key that would be stored on the HSM. Ironically, I've just found out that, since we proposed CloudHSM as a solution to the requirement, [AWS KMS has been validated as FIPS compliant](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/3009). If I'm reading correctly, this means that SSL keys requested through ACM are already stored on a FIPS-compliant HSM and we don't actually need CloudHSM at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this question a year ago, AWS have updated their [documentation on how to set up SSL offload with a CloudHSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-linux.html). By following that documentation, I was able to set up a separate EC2 instance - outside of ElasticBeanstalk - for SSL termination. It's still not possible, AFAIK, to use a CloudHSM directly from within ElasticBeanstalk.